# jquery selector this plus '-rest-of-name'

Tags: jquery, this, selector

I'm trying to condense a code snippet into something that 8 lines instead of 488...help?

Is there a way to use the "this" selector as PART of that name?

This is what I have now (which doesn't work)
http://jsfiddle.net/H44Zj/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="left">
    <div class="showcase show" id="new-online">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="showcase" id="aa-online">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="showcase" id="ab-online">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="showcase" id="ac-online">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="showcase" id="ad-online">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="showcase" id="ae-online">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="showcase" id="af-online">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="showcase" id="ag-online">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

<div class="right">
    <div id="new">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="aa">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="ab">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="ac">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="ad">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="ae">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="af">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="ag">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('#aa,#ab,#ac,#ad,#ae,#af,#ag').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this + '-online').addClass("show");
        $('#new-online').removeClass("show");
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $('#new-online').addClass("show");
        $(this + '-online').removeClass("show");
    });
});
```

I'd like when mouseenter of #aa, add class of show to #aa-online. 
I'd like to not copy/paste this for every (61 of them) element.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` is a **DOM element**. So no, it cannot be part of a selector. It looks like you want to use the element's ID as part of the selector:

```
$('#' + this.id + '-online')
```